# Determining default value from previous arguments

Tags: functions, variable-definitions

How does one specify a default value for an argument which is dependent on the previous arguments of a function?

For instance, consider the function `f[a_, b_:1] := a + b`. Then `f[2]` produces `3`. Now suppose I want `b` to default to `a`. The following code throws an error:

```
f[a_, b_:a] := a + b
```

How is this behavior achieved?

Comment: Can you clean up variables, respectively Start a new kernel? Does anything change?

Comment: I think this question has been asked before.  I am looking.

Comment: Found it.  Closing.

Comment: Thanks, I did some preliminary googling but nothing turned up. Guess I used the wrong search words.